# Default Experience Optimizations TBB not loaded

Tags: sites-9, experience-optimization, template-building-blocks

I am using `Tridion Sites 9` and want to load `Default Building Blocks` for Experience Optimizations in Tridion.

I tried loading Default Building Blocks but I am not seeing it in Tridion.

Below is the process I followed in `Template Builder` to load the `TBBs`:

1. Select Tools
2. Click "Create Default Building Blocks"
3. Select a location for the default TBBs
4. click OK.

Do you know how to load Default Building Block for Experience Optimizations in Tridion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer adds the TBBs to the "default templates" configuration -- which is what is used when you choose "Create Default Building Blocks" in Template Builder. So yes, you need to have XO installed first -- and then you would need to run Template Builder to add the TBBs to a given installation.

It's important to note is that the "Create Default Building Blocks" menu option requires you to choose the *parent* folder where you want the templates to be created. So make sure you do not pick the "Default Templates" folder, but rather its parent (e.g. "Building Blocks").

If you have XO installed but still don't get the TBBs when you install the default templates, perhaps you forgot to restart after the installation? In that case, the configuration hasn't been read again so it doesn't know about the XO TBBs.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, the XO TBBs aren’t created using Template Builder. Instead, they are created when XO is installed as a feature.

By default, the XO TBBs are created (by the installer) in /Building Blocks/Default Templates/Experience Optimization